# Set different page template for 'write review' page

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, template, review

Currently, the page template used for my 'write review' page is a 2-column template. But, this template is already filled with certain static blocks. I'd rather change this page to an 1-column template. How do I do this?

I was also wondering if there is a `.phtml` file that controls this page, since I couldn't find anything when turning on template hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the template from here:

In app/design/frontend/namespace/theme/layout/review.xml

```
<review_product_list translate="label">
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>

</review_product_view>
```